# How to remove exceeding duplicate characters in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program about keyword cipher, got stuck in removing the keyword(alphabet2) characters from the alphabet characters. It ends up having duplicate characters in the end. How do I remove it?
My sample keyword is the word helo and it gives me the result of abcdfgijkmnpqrstuvwxyzzzzz.
How do I remove it?

```
    char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char alphabet2[] = "helo";

for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(alphabet2); i++){
    for(j=0, k=0; j < strlen(alphabet); j++){
        if(alphabet2[i] != alphabet[j]){
            alphabet[k] = alphabet[j];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
puts(alphabet);
```

Comment: `alphabet2[26];` -> `alphabet2[27] = {0];`

Comment: what does UB mean?

Comment: Undefined behavior

Comment: *Undefined Behavior*

Comment: i edited it to show what the sample keyword(alphabet2) is.

Comment: So you will remove the characters of `"helo"` from the larger string?

Comment: yes, that's what i'm heading for.

Answer (score 2):

Your search for characters of one string existing in another string is incorrect. Here is how you fix it:

1. Flip loop's order. The loop on `alphabet` should be on the outside
2. Invert the nested loop. Currently, you stop as soon as you find a non-equal character. Instead, you should look through all characters currently in `alphabet2` before deciding if the next character should be kept or discarded.
3. Null-terminate `alphabet` once you are done processing. This can be done by setting `alphabet[k]` to zero after both loops have finished.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/NQUZbJ)

**Note:** Since you are using string function `strlen`, you might use another string function [`strchr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html) to eliminate the nested loop. Consider doing this as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strchr` to ease things up:

```
size_t len = strlen(alphabet);
size_t k = 0;
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < len; i++){
    if(!strchr(alphabet2,alphabet[i])){
        alphabet[k++]=alphabet[i];
    }
}
alphabet[k]=0;
```

When looping over string - it is not good performance wise to use `strlen` - it would repeatedly calculate length of the string. (which is not needed either). Here we are filtering over the `keyword` letters. Once a letter of `alphabet` is found in `keyword` then it will not be inserted in the `alphabet`.

But on this regard - think of the volume of the text from which you will want to remove the characters of the `keyword`. The better way would be to use an array where each position is mapped to denote the letter `a` to `z`. In this way, before looping, you will just mark `1` for those characters which appear in the `keyword`. This will result in `O(1)` checking when filtering out the characters of `alphabet`.(Yes you need to have some memory for storing the array).

```
int m[26]={0};
size_t len = strlen(alphabet2);
for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
   m[alphabet2[i]-'a']=1;
size_t k = 0;
len = strlen(alphabet);
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < len; i++){
   if(!m[alphabet[i]-'a'])){
      alphabet[k++]=alphabet[i];
    }
}
alphabet[k]=0;
```

In case `keyword` contains `A`-`Z`,you can adapt the whole procedure to take into account those capital letters.